# read dynamodb and get redundant "Decimal" word

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

```
[{'year': Decimal('222'), 'title': 'aaaaaas'}, {'year': Decimal('1111'), 'title': 'dddd'}]
```

when I scan dynamodb table, I got data which is some redundant"Decimal". I want to convert to below. Thanks.

```
[{'year': '222', 'title': 'aaaaaas'}, {'year': '1111', 'title': 'dddd'}]
```

Comment: Why do you want to turn the number into a string?

Comment: I check my dynamodb, "year" type is number, not string, I entry that "year": 222 to dynamodb

Comment: But your example output shows it as a string. `Decimal` is a way of representing numbers in Python; did you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html?

Comment: I have checked your link. It is suitable for single "Decimal" word. Not for a list include "Decimal", But also thank you.

Comment: I don't know why my example output shows it as a string. But I really enter it as a number. Maybe you can try it in AWS?Thanks

Comment: It looks like a string in `'year': Decimal('222')` because that's how Python represents a `Decimal` object. But **you have chosen** to make it a string in `'year': '222'` and it's unclear why. It's also unclear why, if you have read the docs and know how to deal with a `Decimal`, you can't apply that to one that is in a dictionary in a list.

Answer (score 5):

When storing integers in DynamoDB (without doing specific typecasting when adding the data) I find that DynamoDB will store it as a Decimal.

I've made this one-liner to use on items retrieved from DynamoDB, which converts all Decimal values to intergers:

```
item_retrieved_from_db = dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1])) if isinstance(x[1], Decimal) else x, item_retrieved_from_db.items()))
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone still having trouble with this, just create a function named Decimal that returns either a float or a int based on the value.

Just like this:

```
def Decimal(number):
    if float(number)%1==0:
        return int(number)
    return float(number)
```

This way, when iterating over the items, you actually convert the value inside and voi'la.

Answer (score 2):

Using dictionary comprehension, one could do something like this.

```
from decimal import Decimal

item_retrieved_from_db = [{'year': Decimal('222'), 'title': 'aaaaaas'}, {'year': Decimal('1111'), 'title': 'dddd'}]
formatted_item = [{ k:(int(v) if isinstance(v, Decimal) else v) for k, v in d.items() } for d in item_retrieved_from_db]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking Python to print a list of dicts, without telling it how you want it to look. So what it is giving you is the representation you would need to use it in a Python program. And whoever stored the data decided to store `year` as a `Decimal`.

Your "redundant" `Decimal` will disappear if you tell Python how you want your data to look:

```
a =[{'year': Decimal('222'), 'title': 'aaaaaas'}, {'year': Decimal('1111'), 'title': 'dddd'}]
for d in a:
    for (k,v) in d.items():
        print (k,"=",v)

year = 222
title = aaaaaas
year = 1111
title = dddd
```

You don't need to convert the `Decimal` into a `str`. It will print out correctly when the time comes to display it.

Comment: Thank you, now I now why "Decimal" appear.

Comment: I check my dynamodb,  "year" type is number, not string, I entry that "year": 222 to dynamodb

Comment: when I enter your code in aws lambda, it print ""year = {'year': Decimal('222'), 'title': 'aaaaaas'}
\n year = {'year': Decimal('1111'), 'title': 'dddd'}""---"Decimal" still here.

Comment: @KennyChan Sorry, cut'n'paste of the wrong version of the test. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I encountered the same issue, and I solved it using the  [dynamodb_json](https://pypi.org/project/dynamodb-json) module.

```
from dynamodb_json import json_util as ddb_json

result = ddb_json.loads(output_from_dynamodb)
```